# mongoose - Executing a query for each array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array `array = [key1, key2, ..., keyn]`.

I have a schema : `{ key : String, value : String }`.

I'd like to get an array with the values associated to keys (`[value_associated_to_key1, ...]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) is perfect for these situations. When you have one array and want it to result in another array where there's some relation between the respective elements, .map is normally used.

```
var async = require('async');

async.map(array, function (key, next) {
  // Do a query for each key
  model.findOne({ key: key }, function (err, result) {
    // Map the value to the key
    next(err, result.value);
  });
},
function (err, result) {
  console.log(result); // [value1, value 2, ...]
});
```

If you have a lot of keys, async.map might overload the server sine it calls each request in parallel. If so you could use async.eachSeries.

**Update**

Of course it would also be possible to do one query for all of the values:

```
model.find({ key: { $in: array } }, function (err, result) {
  result = result.map(function (document) {
    return document.value;
  });
});
```

The result is now an array of values. However it won't guarantee that they are in the same order as the keys. If the keys are sorted one could do `.find().sort({ key: 1 }).exec(callback)`. Otherwise you'd have to compare it to the key array afterwards, which might be inefficient (but still faster than a query for each key).

Comment: Thanks. And don't you know whether a Mongo based solution exists (e.g. a special request) ?

PS : `findOne` method is more adapted I think. Else replace `result.value` by `result[0].value`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I just realized I was too focused on how to do a query for each and didn't think about that it's possible to do one query for all of the keys at once. I updated my answer with an example.