# Query mongoose for every single element in array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to query mongoose for every single element in an array (which itself is also result of a query to mongoose) and append the result to each array element respected and return the array:

```
Service.find(query)
    .then((servicesList) => {
      const result = [];
      servicesList.forEach((service) => {
        Reviews.find({ service: service._id }).then((revs) => { 
          service.reviews = revs;                                      // Appending the result to element
          result.push(service);                                        // Pushing the element with it appended reviews to the result
        });
      });

      return res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((erro) => {
      return res.json({});
    });
```

but `result` won't get any value because `return res.json(result);`gets called before the `Reviews.find()` returns result

what is the way to solve the problem?

I have checked this :
[mongoose - Executing a query for each array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672601/mongoose-executing-a-query-for-each-array-element)
but it is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.json(result)` is executed *synchronously*, before the individual *asynchronous* `Reviews.find` operations have finished. And this means before the array `result` has received any rows.

Use `Promise.all` to await all asynchronous operations before you return the `result`:

```js
Promise.all(servicesList.map((service) =>
  Reviews.find({service: service._id}).then((revs) => { 
    service.reviews = revs;
    result.push(service);
  })
)).then(function() {
  res.json(result);
})
```

(Alternatively, consider using a join operation on the database to achieve all this with a single `ServiceJoinReview.find` operation.)